# Looping through dataframe in R to perform growth function for missing variables

Tags: r, function, dplyr, nested-loops

I want to calculate the missing values for variable "x1" by adding 1.5% growth for the following years using the first observation (x1=9.4, 11.5, 12.1) for each unique combination of ID and Age. See the following example:

```
#Create data frame
data<- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), Age= c(20,21,22,20,21,22,20,21,22), x1= c(9.4,NA, NA, 11.5, NA, NA, 12.1, NA, NA))
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to mutate the missing NA's using dplyr:

```
df = data %>% group_by(ID, Age) %>% mutate(x1=ifelse(is.na(x1), lag(x1)+ (lag(x1)*0.015), x1))
```

And I have also tried processing it in a nested loop, but do not know how to reference the former missing variable to pass through as an input to the next function, when age increases one year:

```
i<- 1
for(i in 1:length(unique(data$ID))){
  j<-1
  for(j in 1:length(unique(data$Age))) {
   print(x1<- lag(data$x1)+ (lag(data$x1) * 0.015))
    j<- j+1
    
  }
}
```

This is what my resulting dataset should look like:

```
data<- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), Age= c(20,21,22,20,21,22,20,21,22), x1= c(9.4,9.54, 9.68, 11.5, 11.67, 11.84, 12.1, 12.28, 12.46))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  Age= c(20,21,22,20,21,22,20,21,22),
  x1= c(9.4,NA, NA, 11.5, NA, NA, 12.1, NA, NA))


data |>
  group_by(ID, na_group = cumsum(!is.na(x1))) |> 
  mutate(x1 = first(x1) * (1 + 0.015)^(Age - first(Age))) |> 
  ungroup() |> select(!na_group)

# # A tibble: 9 × 3
#      ID   Age    x1
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    20  9.4 
# 2     1    21  9.54
# 3     1    22  9.68
# 4     2    20 11.5 
# 5     2    21 11.7 
# 6     2    22 11.8 
# 7     3    20 12.1 
# 8     3    21 12.3 
# 9     3    22 12.5
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R:

```
transform(data, x1 = ave(x1, ID, FUN = \(x)x[1]*1.015^(seq_along(x)-1)))
  ID Age        x1
1  1  20  9.400000
2  1  21  9.541000
3  1  22  9.684115
4  2  20 11.500000
5  2  21 11.672500
6  2  22 11.847587
7  3  20 12.100000
8  3  21 12.281500
9  3  22 12.465722
```

---

```
data %>%
   mutate(x1 = first(x1)*1.015^(row_number() - 1), .by = ID)

  ID Age        x1
1  1  20  9.400000
2  1  21  9.541000
3  1  22  9.684115
4  2  20 11.500000
5  2  21 11.672500
6  2  22 11.847587
7  3  20 12.100000
8  3  21 12.281500
9  3  22 12.465722
```